# Android Studio Error findViewByID

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I recently added a library to my project during which I edited my gradle settings.

Following this whenever I use the findViewById() function in an activity it is highlighted red and and error message appears stating that it Cannot resolve findViewByID.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

I am not even sure what to post to get better answers.

Here is what I changed.

app: build.gradle:

Added the following line:

```
compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':slideDateTimePicker'
project(':slideDateTimePicker').projectDir = new File('libs/slideDateTimePicker')
```

The files were stored in the lib directory in the project.

Invalidating the cache and rebuilding seems to correct the issue.

Comment: Check Problem/Error tab of studio(in bottom) and see what errors are.

Comment: try: file -> invalidate caches/restart and then build->rebuild project

Comment: Rebuilding the cache seems to solve the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: more detail in the question please?

Comment: Looks like you misconfigured the project in the Gradle settings and now it can no longer be build correctly. Try to check what exactly you changed in Gradle, undo it or post it here - without additional details, it will be impossible to help you.